# Excel Spreadsheet to HTML Chart dynamically

Tags: javascript, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet that is going to be updated monthly and then displayed on a Blackberry browser.  I've already created a website that has all the spreadsheet information in their statically and uses HTML definition lists and CSS to create charts.

I'm looking for a way to load a new spreadsheet into the server each month and have the website update accordingly.  I've started creating JavaScript variables in the HTML page so they can be changed whenever a new dataset is received.  However, I'm struggling with how to set the data to the variables without manual entry.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There are javascript codes to read CSV files.

Just search for: javascript CSV

Take CSV2TABLE as an example:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/csv2table